# Selenium Web driver - No such element error while clicking an element

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Script in UI

```
<div class=navdeactive><a href="technology.html">Technology</a></div>
```

While executing the below script

```
@driver.find_element(:link_text, "Technology").click
```

Getting an error>>

> Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchElementError: The element could not
>   be found

But in view, source link is available.

Web Driver version: **selenium-webdriver (2.25.0)**

Help me on this

Answer (score 1):

Based on your question you can  use xpath and click the particular Html locator.
i have been given below script using python web driver. try this one.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[text()='Technology']").click()
```

Comment: @Senthil Thanks for your reply.... We can use xpath.. But I would like to know why ":link" command is not working. FYI: just now I came to know 'link' command is not working during the HTML page selection _script for the below lines is not working_ **<a href="solutions.html">
Solutions
</a>'**   Unable to click the solution link _Script for the below lines are working_ **<a href="/login">
login
</a>**

Answer (score 1):

Answer: 
In UI text is displayed as **TECHNOLOGY** But in the Page View Source text is displayed as **Technology**  I have changed the code as @driver.find_element(:link_text, "TECHNOLOGY").click...... Now its worked fine...